# updating time out values in select() calls

Tags: c, linux, select, timer

I want to implement a timer using select() and I want it to reach the timeout code after intervals of every 3 seconds.

if I remove "timeout.tv_sec+=8;" from my code it waits for 3 seconds and then starts printing "time out" continuously and with "timeout.tv_sec+=8" nothing gets printed, the program gets stuck. Nothing gets printed. Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong in this?
My code is as follows :
Basically, I want it to print time out at an interval of 3 seconds.

```
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 3;
while(1) {
  int rc = select(2, NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
  if(rc == 0)
  {
      printf("  time out  "); 
      timeout.tv_sec+=8;
  }      
  if (rc < 0)
  {
      printf("  Error  ");
      continue;
  }
  else
  {
     printf("  process  ");// some instructions
  }
}
```

Comment: "the code does not work" is no problem description. Also for this case you should describe what happens.

Comment: true its sounds  ambigous, thanks Gerhardh, I edited the question.

Comment: After re-reading the question I am not sure what you want to achieve. Do you want to use `select` simply to generate a 3s timer interval? Or do you want to access sockets and apply a timeout?

Comment: At t =3 print timeout t=6 print timeout t =9 print timeout and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a combination of two problems.

- on Linux, the time out struct is modified by `select` to indicate how much time is left
- `printf` uses buffered IO. Text written using `printf` remains in a buffer in the program until either `\n` is printed or `fflush` is called on `stdout` or the buffer is full.

If you omit `timeout.tv_sec+=8`, your code waits 3 seconds, then prints `time out` except it only goes to an internal buffer in the program. The next time round the loop, the time out is now zero, so the program prints `time out` to the buffer straight away. The same for any subsequent executions of the loop. Fairly quickly the buffer gets filled up and the program flushes it to `stdout` at which point you will see it on the screen.

If you leave in `timeout.tv_sec+=8` on the first iteration the `select` waits 3 seconds, on the second and each subsequent iteration, it waits 8 seconds. This means it takes much longer to fill up the buffer, so it will be much longer before you see any output. You print 10 `char`s. If the internal buffer is 4096 bytes, it will take about 55 minutes to print anything at all.

To fix it, either put a `\n` on each print statement, or `fflush` stdout regularly.

There is one other thing you need to do and that is to set `timeout.tv_usec` to 0 each time you set `timeout.tv_sec`. Your code, as it stands leaves half the `struct` uninitialised and therefore invokes undefined behaviour.

```
struct timeval timeout;
while(1) {
  timeout.tv_sec = 3 ;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0; // Otherwise UB!
  int rc = select(2, NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
  if(rc == 0)
  {
      printf("  time out  "); 
  }      
  if (rc < 0)
  {
      printf("  Error  ");
      break; // The error is unlikely to go away next time around
  }
  else
  {
     printf("  process  ");// some instructions
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer Jeremy. This explained everything really well.

Comment: I have one question though, if i put timeout.tv_sec+=8, then the code waits for 8 seconds. I am guessing this happens because the timeout value had reached zero and it gets reinitialized again. So, basically its same as timeout.tv_sec =8, correct?

Comment: @VikramSingh You are correct. You are effectively doing `timeout.tv_sec = 0 + 8`

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to reset your timeout value.
Before `select` returns, the timeout value is updated. It then contains only the remaining time.

If you don't update at all, you get the following problem:

Once you run out of time, you hit the timeout immediately in every following call.

If you update with `+=8` you would increase the remaining timeout. If you have 2.5s left, it gets 10.5s and so on.

To avoid this, just set it to 3s again:

```
while(1) {
  int rc = select(2, NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
  timeout.tv_sec = 3;
  ...
```

BTW: You might get better results if you provided some file descriptors to `select` for which you want to wait.

Another observation:

You don't add `\n` in your `printf` calls. This will not trigger flushing your `stdout`. You might well print everything but it is just not moved from the buffer to the terminal.

Comment: it freezes, nothing gets printed.

Comment: Please see my update. You just don't see your prints.

Comment: Exactly thanks! I was not flushing out to stdout. Yes, I am eventually monitoring the readfds but was stuck at this part, couldn't understand what was going wrong